# Updating a component that is not mounted, according to console

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am getting some data from a database, which is an array of objects (songs). I would like to show 5 songs at a time, because there are more than 800, and the program slows down a lot if I try to load them all at once.

My react part works fine if I load the songs directly, but I am trying to create another state, that stores only 5 objects at a time, and display those 5, while I have another state called "songs", that will set it's state at the beginning, storing 800+ songs. When I try to store this 5 in another state, the program crashes.

I appreciate any help in understanding my mistake.

I have tried setting a console.log inside the useEffect that modifies the showSongs but esLint (i think it's esLint) keeps modifying the array at the end of the function, adding some code I don't want inside it.

I can't do showSongs.map, but I can do songs.map (But songs will have more than 800 songs, so I want to display showSongs).

```
function MySongsForm() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState({ quantity: 0 });
  const [showSongs, setShow] = useState([]);
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSong, setSelected] = useState({ song: "" });
  const [recommendations, setRecommendations] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      const res = await requestMySongs();
      setSongs(res);
    }
    getData();
  }, [setSongs]);

  async function submitSong() {
    const recs = await recommendationRequest(selectedSong.song);
    setRecommendations(recs.tracks);
  }

  function UpdateSelected(event) {
    event.persist();
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setSelected({ song: event.target.value });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let newList = [];
    for (let i = offset.quantity; i < offset.quantity + 5; i++) {
      newList.push(songs[i]);
    }
    setShow(newList);
  }, [offset.quantity, setSongs, songs]);

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <RadioGroup>
          {showSongs.map((song, index) => {
            return (
              <FormControlLabel
                control={<Radio />}
                key={index}
                value={song.song_spotify_id}
                name="songInput"
                onClick={e => UpdateSelected(e)}
                label={song.name}
              />
            );
          })}
        </RadioGroup>
        <Button onClick={() => submitSong()}>Select Song</Button>
      </FormControl>
      <DisplaySongs songs={recommendations} />
    </div>


  );
}
```

The error I am getting in the browser is:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'song_spotify_id' of undefined

The error I am getting at the same time in the console is:

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

edit:

edit:

I have checked but I don't know what I am looking for. If I remove the following function, it works:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let newList = [];
    for (let i = offset.quantity; i < offset.quantity + 5; i++) {
      newList.push(songs[i]);
    }
    setShow(newList);
  }, [offset.quantity, setSongs, songs]);
```

Comment: Using hooks is not recommended, because of this kind of unexpected behaviours

Comment: @Bob This is total nonsense. The same effect does occur with class based components when having an async callback updating the state after the component has been unmounted. Totally unrelated to hooks.

Comment: Eslint is a static code analyser. It does not in any way modify your code nor does it do anything at runtime.

Comment: My comment is not related to how do hooks work. I am already familiar with. It is about how the code looks like and hard to debug and complex to write in my opinion. Sorry if it annoyed you guys

Comment: @Bob Why are you then claiming that hooks aren't recommended when in fact they are explicitly encouraged to be used? If used correctly there is no unexpected behaviour caused by them. This is independent of whether you like the syntax.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification, I think I heard about not recommended from some facebook developer talks or video lessons.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have an async function trying to update your state after the component has been unmounted. Code execution continues while your async handler is e.g. awaiting the response of a network request. In that time something already led to your component unmounting.

Check the component rendering your `MySongsForm`. Something makes it unmount before an async handler inside of it is trying to update the state.

Comment: I have checked but I don't know what I am looking for. If I remove the following function, it works:
```
  useEffect(() => {
    let newList = [];
    for (let i = offset.quantity; i < offset.quantity + 5; i++) {
      newList.push(songs[i]);
    }
    setShow(newList);
  }, [offset.quantity, setSongs, songs]);
```

Comment: @Max If you want to add some information use the edit function to edit your question. Do not post code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function setDisplay() {
      let newList = [];
      for (let i = offset.quantity; i < offset.quantity + 5; i++) {
        newList.push(songs[i]);
      }
      console.log(newList);
      setShow(newList);
    }
    if (songs.length !== 0) {
      setDisplay();
    }
  }, [offset, songs]);
```

This solved it.